# regexr how to exclude a string match

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to match the following:

any string which contains any character, except / or . this is done using `([^/\.]+)`, how ever, I also want to add a string "faq" so to match any character, except if it's a string of "faq", some examples:

Currently, my Regex:

```
^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/$
```

However, it captures "faq" aswell.

```
faq/fsdfsd/ => No match
faqgff/fdsfs/ => Match
jhpo/ijkd/ => Match
f/iout/ => Match
a/iout/ => Match
q/iout/ => Match
```

I've tried running ([^/.]+)

Yes, it's for .htaccess redirects :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a negative lookhead

```
(?!.*faq)
```

it is true when it does not find the pattern "faq"

So include it in your regex like this

```
^(?!.*faq)([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/$
```

Then it will match for your pattern, but fail if the string includes "faq". (Hope I understood you correctly)

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uon0)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I fully understand your problem statement:

> want to add a string "faq" so to match any character, except if it's a
>   string og "faq"

However, it sounds like [negative lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) *might* be the tool for the job: https://serverfault.com/questions/78624/apache-2-negative-filesmatch-filesnotmatch